# Prevent refresh of page when submit button in modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, bootstrap-modal

I have two bootstrap modals which is a modal within a modal. Modal 2 contains search list. Which means, there is a search box for user to input a name. There is also a table to display the retrieved list. I would like to put a select button in the table. So when I clicked the select button, modal 2 closed. Only modal1 is left with data from selected rows. The first problem I have is in modal2 on how to submit the search word and retrieve the list of result in table. I tried the code below but it keeps refeshing my page in which I have top re-open the modal to see the result. The search button worked since it displays the data. I want to submit the search word without refreshing my page. At the same time, the content in my modal should be updated.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1"  role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Open second modal</button>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade in" id="modal2" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal2">Modal 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="get"
                    <div Class="form-group">
                        <Label Class="control-label col-md-2">Name</Label>
                        <div Class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" name="strName" Class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="search" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="col-md-1" style="text-align:center">ID</th>
                                <th class="col-md-8" style="text-align:center">Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @for Each Item In Model
                                @<tr>
                                    <td class="col-md-8">@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) Item.name)</td>
                                </tr>
                            Next
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <Button type="button" Class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use AJAX to submit requests to the server and update your page based on the results it returns.

Comment: Is there another way to do this instead of using ajax?

Comment: You can't use AJAX? There are harder ways to do it but that takes submitting and refreshing the page and then rebuilding it dynamically based on the results.AJAX is easier and built for this.